# ContextMenuStrip events in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have a ContextMenuStrip and I'd like to assign event handlers in the designer for its ToolStripMenuItems.  If I choose to edit the item collection, I can edit the properties of the ToolStripMenuItems that I add, but I cannot figure out how to edit the event handlers.  I could just do it in code, but that seems silly.  There should be a way to do it in the designer.  What is the obvious thing that I'm missing?

EDIT: The ContextMenuStrip is in a custom control that inherits TreeView.

[image]

I have to choose Edit Items where I can see the properties of the item, but not the events.

Answer (score 10):

In the property tool directly under the title bar there is a drop down menu that you can use to select any of the controls in the current context. Select the menu item you want then go to the Events (Thunderbolt Icon) like you would for any other control.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by using the Forms Designer exactly as you would for any other control.

Click the cmsItem box and the ContextMenuStrip should appear attached to the top of the Form currently in the designer.

Now click the root ContextMenuStrip item on the form and you should see all sub-items.

By clicking a sub-item and navigating to properties (right-click, or F4, or what-not), you can manage any events or properties.

Comment: That's just it.  There is no form in designer, just the custom control.  I've tried and it simply will not display the editor you're talking about.  I finally gave up and stuck it in the code.

Comment: worked for me. Selecting tsmiNew in the properties window gave me access to all the events

Comment: It is not working for me in Visual Studio 2015.  There is no events icon, just as in the screenshot in the question. (I also have a ContextMenuStrip as the parent of the ToolStripMenuItem.)